# "Best practice" or "design pattern" to group a class with "associated" classes in an object-oriented language

Tags: object-oriented, python, class-design

Sometimes a class `A` can have an "associated" class `B` such that the implementation of `B` depends on the implementation of `A`. For example, this can happen when `B`'s objects are to be created by `A`'s objects and are to be "linked" to their creator object.

An example from Python: [dictionary view objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) are created by certain dictionary methods.

My problem: I am implementing an implicit graph in Python, and in addition to the class `Node` of nodes of this graph, I wish to have a class `NeighbourExplorer` whose objects contain more state than a simple node but allow more efficient access to and iteration over neighbour nodes.

If the "main" class is subclassed, the "associated" class may need to be subclassed too.  Thus, when using inheritance, extra care must be taken to keep the classes synchronised.

What would be an appropriate object-oriented approach to group such classes together?  If Python dictionaries and dictionary views were implemented in Python, how would it be done?

Currently, for the implicit graph example, I am thinking about just making the "associated class" an attribute of the "main class":

```py
class Node:
    ...
    class NeighbourExplorer:
        ...
```

Comment: Aren’t `NeigbourExplorer`s improved nodes ? If so, why not simply use these instead of simple nodes ? Since they extend nodes, that shouldn’t be a problem.

Comment: @SteveChamaillard, they are not improved nodes, they contain redundant information/state, and may not even contain the current node in a readily available form. Dictionary views are not improved dictionaries either.

Comment: Well, you can put them in the same file, or nest them as you have done. Sometimes you have several objects that collaborate; this is not unlike the aggregate concept found in DDD. There, an aggregate encapsulates its collaborating objects behind one chosen object (aggregate root) that provides the interface for the whole thing and acts as a facade of sorts that maintains invariants. Your "associated" classes can either be an internal implementation detail of the aggregate, or interface classes - data structures and objects that you return from or pass to the methods of the aggregate root.

Comment: Did you consider splitting your code to different modules/packages/projects (depending on the language)? Many times the need for nested classes is indicating that you have a monolith class holding too many responsibilities.

Comment: @PanthersFan92, as i said, the classes in question are mutually dependent. How would you split Python dictionaries and dictionary views into two modules?

Comment: You asked for an OO approach, and that would probably be to separate your code into single responsibility classes with well defined interfaces between them. Objects can be dependent without being in the same file/class.

Comment: But it's really hard to give a more informed answer because it's unclear what this `NeighbourExplorer` class or why it's necessary.

Comment: @PanthersFan92, I may appreciate if you give an example with dictionary and dictionary view. This is what i asked in my previous comment.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović, thanks for the ideas. Are there any design patterns for organising "interface classes" you mentioned?

Comment: Not really design patterns (although what you have there seems to be a form of the Iterator pattern - your could see your NeighbourExplorer as an iterator). Different people do different things - again, two organizational options that come to mind are to define in same file or to nest. In C# for example, if I want to implement a specialized iterator ("enumerator") that's very closely related to one other type, I can declare a private nested class that implements the public `IEnumerator<T>` interface.

Comment: That impl is entirely managed by the containing class, though. In other languages you can do something like that by convention. It's a bit of a judgement call. A very generic class that's used all over should be declared separately (e.g., (x, y, z) - vectors in graphics applications), but if you have a special-purpose class that clients need to deal with try to somehow associate it with the others (couple of classes in the same folder, or in the same file). If the type is managed by, and private to the outer type, declare it as a nested class, and maybe prefix the class name with _.